# magento tracking pixel checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I'm trying to integrate a tracking pixel into the magento success page. For testing I build the following code and implemented it into line > 45 in success.phtml file within the template folder. Actually the variables are all empty. What's wrong?

```
<?php 
<?php 
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId(); 
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load($lastOrderId); 
$skus = array(); 
$qtys = array(); 
$amounts = array(); 
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item){ 
$skus[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getSku(); 
$names[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getName(); 
$qtys[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered() * 1; 
$amounts[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getRowTotal() * 100;//or $item->getPrice()*$item->getQtyOrdered();//but this will ignore any applied coupons 
} 
$skuspipe = implode("|", $skus); 
$namespipe = implode("|", $names); 
$qtyspipe = implode("|", $qtys); 
$amountspipe = implode("|", $amounts); 

<!--
OrderID: <?php echo $orderID; ?>
skus: <?php print_r($skus); ?>
names: <?php print_r($names); ?>
qtys: <?php print_r($qtys); ?>
amounts: <?php print_r($amounts); ?>
skupipe: <?php echo $skupipe; ?> 
namespipe: <?php echo $namespipe; ?>
qtyspipe: <?php echo $qtyspipe; ?>
amountspipe: <?php echo $amountspipe; ?>
-->
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Collections, Magento often only loads kind of a stub of data for each item.

You could load the whole objects by using

```
$item->load( $item->getId() );
```

on each iteration.

Also, try to debug output the collection first to see if there are any items found.